# Qual a diferença entre static e self em PHP?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos

Qual é a diferença entre `static` e `self`? Exemplifique com situações que justifiquem seus diferentes usos. O que isso tem a ver com *late static binding*?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`static` é usado para definir que um método ou atributo em uma classe é estático. Isso significa (como alguém que conhece de OO deve saber) que aquele método/atributo pertence à classe e não à uma instância dela e, por isso, pode ser acessado sem instânciar um novo objeto.

Exemplo:

```
<?php
class Foo
{
    public static $meu_estatico = 'foo';

    public function valorEstatico() {
        return self::$meu_estatico;
    }
}
```

É possível usar durante a execução do código algo como :

```
print Foo::$meu_estatico . "\n";
```

Puro assim, sem ser necessário fazer um `$a = new Foo()` antes.

Perceba no exemplo que foi usada o `self`, que também foi questionado. Ele tão somente é usado para utilizar uma variável estática dentro da classe que a contém.

```
$a = new Foo();
echo $a->valorEstatico() // tem como saída "foo"
```

É importante deixar claro que um valor estático pertence à classe e não às instâncias, mas podem ser usados dentro da classe via `self`.

Isso é muito interessante para valores que você queira disponíveis para toda a aplicação, por exemplo. Se eles mudarem na classe uma única vez toda a aplicação tem acesso aos mesmos valores.

Esses exemplos foram retirados de http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.static.php

**APÓS UPDATE DA PERGUNTA . . .**

Quando uma classe utiliza um método estático que foi herdado de outra, valores estáticos dentro desse método herdado farão referência à classe mãe caso seja usado o `self`. Para utilizar a classe especializada (filha) como referência para esses valores estáticos, utiliza-se o self static binding. Entenda binding como "ligação" (não sei se ajuda muito) .Citando a doc e um exemplo:

> Este recurso foi nomeado "late static bindings" com um pespectiva
>   interna em mente. "Late binding" vem do fato que static:: não ser mais
>   resolvido usando a classe onde o mesmo é definido mas ele será
>   avaliado usando informação em tempo de execução. Ele foi também
>   chamado "static binding" como pode ser usado para (mas não é limitado
>   para) chamada de métodos estáticos.
>   (http://php.net/lsb)

Exemplos (também dos docs, mas fundi os dois)

```
<?php
class A {
    public static function who() {
        echo __CLASS__;
    }
    public static function test() {
        self::who(); // Isso vai sair como "A", o nome da classe mãe 
    } 
    public static function test2() {
        static::who(); // Já esse aqui vai sair "B", o nome da classe filha    
    }  
}  

class B extends A {      
    public static function who() {
         echo __CLASS__;
    }  
}   

B::test(); // Isso vai sair como "A", o nome da classe mãe 
B::test2(); // Já esse aqui vai sair "B", o nome da classe filha  
?>
```

Answer (score 11):

`self` serve para acessar propriedades da classe dentro dela mesma, ou seja, para todas as instancias só existirá um único valor já que a propriedade é de classe.
`static` é um qualificador que gera uma propriedade da classe ao invés de uma propriedade do objeto ou instância da classe, o código abaixo exemplifica o uso dos dois e também diferencia uma propriedade de um objeto da classe de uma propriedade da classe:

```php
<?php
    class X {
        private $non_static_member = 1; //propriedade do objeto da classe
        private static $static_member = 2; // propriedade da classe

        function __construct() {
            // Acessando propriedade do objeto da classe
            echo $this->non_static_member . ' '
              // Acessando propriedade da classe  
              . self::$static_member;
        }
    }
    // Precisamos instanciar a classe para acessar as propriedades do objeto criado.
    (new X())->$non_static_member;
    // Acessamos a partir da classe.
    X::static_member

?>
```

Basicamente late static binding é utilizado para referenciar uma especialização(classe filha) a partir de uma implementação realizada na classe generalizada(classe mãe), permitindo o polimorfismo entre as classes filhas.

```php
<?php
    class DartVader {
        public static function say() {
           echo "I'm your father";
        }
        public static function sayToLuky() {
           self::say(); // "I'm your father" 
        } 
        public static function sayToDartVader() {
           static::say(); // Can be "Han Solo my love!" or "Noooooo!"    
        }
    }

    class Luke extends DartVader {      
        public static function say() {
            echo "Noooooo!";
        }  
    }   

    class Leia extends DartVader {
        public static function say() {
            echo "Han Solo my love!";
        }
    }

    Leia::sayToDartVader() // "Han Solo my love!"
    Leia::sayToLuky() // "I'm your father"
    Luke::sayToDartVader() // "Noooooo!"
    Luke::sayToLuky() // "I'm your father"
?>
```

Comment: +1, sendo +0.5 pela corretude e +0.5 pelas referências a Star Wars.

Answer (score 4):

## Self

A keyword `self` Acessa uma propriedade dentro da classe e é equivalente ao: `$this`. Ex.:

```
class Foo {
  function __construct() {
    return self::bar();
  }

  public function bar() {
    return "bar";
  }
}
```

Ao executar `$foo = new Foo()` é retornado o valor da função bar dentro da classe.

## Static

A keyword `static` torna uma função acessível sem necessidade de instanciar a classe onde ele está "hospedada". Por exemplo:

```
class Foo {
  public static function bar() {
    return get_class() . "bar";
  }
}
echo Foo::bar();
```

Nesse código será imprimido `Foobar`. Recapitulando `self` serve para acessar funções ou variáveis que estão dento de uma classe e é equivalente ao `$this`, já `static` serve para acessar funções ou variáveis sem necessidade de chamar uma classe.

### *Late Static Bindings*

É quanto é herdado por outra classe atributos estáticos.

Answer (score 0):

Dadas as excelentes respostas, quero enfatizar a questão da **herança**. Mas antes, vamos recapitular o seguinte:

---

## `self`:

É usado para retornar o valor de uma propriedade ou chamar (executar) algum método estático - DEVE ser usado **DENTRO** da classe em questão com o operador `::`;

## `static`:

É usado para:

1. Declarar que uma propriedade ou um método é estático. Ou seja: não é necessário instanciar a classe em questão (`new MinhaClasse();`);
2. Retornar o valor de uma propriedade estática ou chamar (executar) algum método estático - PODE ser usado **DENTRO E FORA** da classe em questão com o mesmo operador `::`;

---

## Herança

Considere o seguinte código:

```
class Foo
{
    public static $variavel = 'Valor A';

    public static function valorVariavel
    {
        return self::$variavel;
    }
}

echo Foo::valorVariavel(); // retorna "Valor A" que pertence a classe "Foo";
```

Declarei a classe `Foo` com o método estático `valorVariavel()` que retorna o valor da **propriedade estática** `$variavel`. Em seguida chamei o **método estático** com o operador `::` (ao invés do operador `->`).

Agora que vem o *pulo-do-gato*! Considere o seguinte código:

```
class Bar extends Foo
{
    public static $variavel = 'Valor B';
}

echo Bar::valorVariavel(); // retorna "Valor A" que pertence a classe "Foo";
```

Na classe `Bar` declarei a propriedade estática `$variavel` com valor `Valor B`, mas ao chamar o método, retorna `Valor A`.

Isso acontece porque o `self` retorna *aquilo que está na sua classe*. Seja propriedade ou método.

Para contornar isso, podemos retornar o valor da propriedade com `static`, ao invés de `self`:

```
class Foo
{
    public static $variavel = 'Valor A';

    public static function valorVariavel()
    {
        return static::$variavel;
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo
{
    public static $variavel = 'Valor B';
}

echo Foo::valorVariavel(); // retorna "Valor A" que pertence a classe "Foo";
echo Bar::valorVariavel(); // retorna "Valor B" que pertence a classe "Bar";
```

Com `static`, retornamos sempre **o valor da ÚLTIMA DECLARAÇÃO**, seguindo a ordem da herança (veja no próximo exemplo).

É legal, também, sempre declarar as propriedades estáticas nas classes-filhas quando se pretende alterar seu valor. Ou então será sobrescrito o valor da classe-pai (que foi estendida). Oque acabaria afetando todas as outras classes que estendem esta mesma classe-pai e que estejam sendo instanciadas/chamadas posteriormente no mesmo *script* (execução).

Veja este exemplo:

```
class Foo
{
    public static $variavel = 'Valor A';

    public static function valorVariavel()
    {
        return static::$variavel;
    }

    public static function setVariavel($valor)
    {
        static::$variavel = $valor;
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo
{
    // propriedade não foi declarada
}

class FooBar extends Foo
{
    public static $variavel = 'Valor D';
}


echo Foo::valorVariavel(); // retorna "Valor A" que pertence a classe "Foo";

echo Bar::valorVariavel(); // retorna "Valor A" que pertence a classe "Bar";

Bar::setVariavel('Valor C');

echo Foo::valorVariavel(); // retorna "Valor C" que pertence a classe "Foo";

echo Bar::valorVariavel(); // retorna "Valor C" que pertence a classe "Bar";

echo FooBar::valorVariavel(); // retorna "Valor D" que pertence a classe "FooBar";

FooBar::setVariavel('Valor E');

echo Foo::valorVariavel(); // retorna "Valor C" que pertence a classe "Foo";

echo Bar::valorVariavel(); // retorna "Valor C" que pertence a classe "Bar";

echo FooBar::valorVariavel(); // retorna "Valor E" que pertence a classe "FooBar";
```

Quando iniciei o aprendizado de *POO*, tomei uma "bendita coça" com essas diferenças de `static` para `self`. Espero que isso possa esclarecer a questão da **herança**.