# PDO PHP Microsoft SQL SERVER

Tags: php, sql-server

Pessoal tenho essa classe que conecta com banco mysql, como posso usar para conectar ao microsoft SQL Server ?

```
<?php

abstract class database {
    /* Método construtor do banco de dados */

    private function __construct() {

    }

    /* Evita que a classe seja clonada */

    private function __clone() {

    }

    /* Método que destroi a conexão com banco de dados e remove da memória todas as variáveis setadas */

    public function __destruct() {
        $this->disconnect();
        foreach ($this as $key => $value) {
            unset($this->$key);
        }
    }

    private static $dbtype = "mysql";
    private static $host = "localhost";
    private static $port = "3306";
    private static $user = "root";
    private static $password = "";
    private static $db = "banco";


    /* Metodos que trazem o conteudo da variavel desejada
      @return   $xxx = conteudo da variavel solicitada */

    private function getDBType() {
        return self::$dbtype;
    }

    private function getHost() {
        return self::$host;
    }

    private function getPort() {
        return self::$port;
    }

    private function getUser() {
        return self::$user;
    }

    private function getPassword() {
        return self::$password;
    }

    private function getDB() {
        return self::$db;
    }

    private function connect() {
        try {
            $this->conexao = new PDO($this->getDBType() . ":host=" . $this->getHost() . ";port=" . $this->getPort() . ";dbname=" . $this->getDB(), $this->getUser(), $this->getPassword());
        } catch (PDOException $i) {
            //se houver exceção, exibe
            die("Erro: <code>" . $i->getMessage() . "</code>");
        }

        return ($this->conexao);
    }

    private function disconnect() {
        $this->conexao = null;
    }

    /* Método select que retorna um VO ou um array de objetos */

    public function selectDB($sql, $params = null, $class = null) {
        $query = $this->connect()->prepare($sql);
        $query->execute($params);

        if (isset($class)) {
            $rs = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, $class) or die(print_r($query->errorInfo(), true));
        } else {
            //$rs = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ) or die(print_r($query->errorInfo(), true));
            $rs = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        }
        self::__destruct();
        return $rs;
    }

    /* Método insert que insere valores no banco de dados e retorna o último id inserido */

    public function insertDB($sql, $params = null) {
        $conexao = $this->connect();
        $query = $conexao->prepare($sql);
        $query->execute($params);
        $rs = $conexao->lastInsertId() or die(print_r($query->errorInfo(), true));
        self::__destruct();
        return $rs;
    }

    /* Método update que altera valores do banco de dados e retorna o número de linhas afetadas */

    public function updateDB($sql, $params = null) {
        $query = $this->connect()->prepare($sql);
        $query->execute($params);
        $rs = $query->rowCount() or die(print_r($query->errorInfo(), true));
        self::__destruct();
        return $rs;
    }

    /* Método delete que excluí valores do banco de dados retorna o número de linhas afetadas */

    public function deleteDB($sql, $params = null) {
        $query = $this->connect()->prepare($sql);
        $query->execute($params);
        $rs = $query->rowCount() or die(print_r($query->errorInfo(), true));
        self::__destruct();
        return $rs;
    }

}
```

PS: uso o php do xamp e mac osx, estou conectando em um sql server remoto....

Obg

Comment: Posta seu código aqui, junto a sua pergunta. O link irá expirar com o tempo e, quando isso acontecer, sua pergunta, da maneira que está, não fará sentido.

Comment: Pronto, desculpe

Comment: Aproveita o embalo e posta sua tentativa e possíveis erros que ocorreram.

Comment: O erro é drive não encontrado, uso o php do xamp no mac, estou conectando em uma maquina da rede... Por enquanto o erro é esse ...

Comment: Isso ajuda? [Drivers PDO para SQL Server](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/48078).

Comment: O problema em ambas as respostas é que uso o php do xamp e no mac

Comment: E você não acha que essas informações são importantes a ponto de estarem na sua pergunta?

Comment: vdd, desculpe irei alterar ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solução rápida, troque essas linhas com os dados do Sql Server:

```
private static $dbtype = "sqlsrv"; //aquivo troca para sqlsrv
private static $host = "ip";
private static $port = "3306";
private static $user = "root";
private static $password = "";
private static $db = "banco";

private function connect() {
    try {
        $this->conexao = new PDO($this->getDBType() . ":Server=" . $this->getHost() . ";port=" . $this->getPort() . ";Database=" . $this->getDB(), $this->getUser(), $this->getPassword());
    } catch (PDOException $i) {
        //se houver exceção, exibe
        die("Erro: <code>" . $i->getMessage() . "</code>");
    }

    return ($this->conexao);
}
```

Solução mais lenta, porém mais extensivel. Troca todos private por protected, assim classes que herdam sua classe podem ver e modificar esses métodos, e todos os self:: por static:: (para você mudar o valor das propriedades e a sua classe filha usar a modificação dela). Para entender melhor  self:: e static:: clique [neste link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6434/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-static-e-self-em-php)

Feita essas substituições crie uma nova classe, e a utilize para conectar na base de dados

```
class sqlServerDatabase extends database
{
    private static $dbtype = "sqlsrv"; //aquivo troca para sqlsrv
    private static $host = "ip";
    private static $port = "3306";
    private static $user = "root";
    private static $password = "";
    private static $db = "banco";

private function connect() {
    try {
        $this->conexao = new PDO($this->getDBType() . ":Server=" . $this->getHost() . ";port=" . $this->getPort() . ";Database=" . $this->getDB(), $this->getUser(), $this->getPassword());
    } catch (PDOException $i) {
        //se houver exceção, exibe
        die("Erro: <code>" . $i->getMessage() . "</code>");
    }

    return ($this->conexao);
}
}
```

O segundo método permite que você não precise ficar alterando sua classe database toda vez que for conectar em um banco novo, basta herdá-la. Esse é um dos princípios do [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)), mais especificamente o O.

Para o caso de não encontrar o driver, você deve habilitá-lo no seu php.ini,como é Sql Server em geral você vai ter que instalar o driver, eu começaria por este [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/cc296203(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: Ele da driver não encontrado... como colocaria o drive no php do xamp ? Pois é nele que estou testando ...

Comment: Acredito que você tenha que fazer o download(e colocar na pasta php/ext) e ajustar no php.ini Tem um link na resposta que pode ajudar

Comment: o problema que uso o xamp e no mac ....

Comment: o download é .exe não tem essa opção no mac ....

Comment: Isso já virou uma outra pergunta no SO, sua classe eu arrumei agora instalar driver do sql server no mac, nem sei se tem, díficilmente alguém roda um servidor no mac...

Comment: Ok, obrigado...