# Php conexao com SQL Server

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

Como posso conectar o o php com sqlserver (pdo)? Parece simples, mas não estou conseguindo...
Já habilitei o driver tudo ok 
Em anexo tem o nome do servidor, vou rodar no local ...[image]

Comment: Qual o código que você está utilizando para conexão?

Comment: Tentei varios ja... mas sem sucesso... a classe q sempre uso no mysql/postgtee é essa: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/182026/32918

Answer (score 4):

Você tem duas opções para tentar:

```
$pdo = new PDO ("mssql:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbname","$username","$pw");
```

ou

```
$pdo = new PDO( "sqlsrv:server=$serverName ; Database=$dbname", "$username", "$pw");
```

Depende o driver que você instalou no PHP.

[Editado] Um exemplo de select com PDO

```
//retornar o resultset
$sql = 'Select * from products';
$result = $pdo->query($sql);

// imprimir resultados um a um 
while ($campos = $result->fetch()){
    echo $campos['ProductID']. ' - '.$campos['ProductName'].'<br />';
}
```

Comment: e como seria um select ppor exemplo ? O server name é o nome do servidor ? esse que postei na foto selecionado em azul ?

Comment: Resposta editada com exemplo.

Comment: infelizmente sem sucesso... A pagina fica carregando até timeout, tem como me ajudar ?

Comment: Não mostra erro? Já deu uma olhada na rede?

Comment: Com a segunda tentativa deu o erro : Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver' in C:\xampp\htdocs\teste\1.php:2 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\teste\1.php(2): PDO->__construct('sqlsrv:server=D...', 'sa', 'Gugofu3107') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\teste\1.php on line 2.
Já o primeiro é : Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\teste\1.php on line 0

Comment: O phpinfo na área de PDO exibe : PDO drivers 
mssql, mysql, odbc, sqlite, sqlite2

Comment: A mensagem da primeira é clara, você não tem esse driver instalado. Na segunda é timeout, pode ter inúmeros motivos, o SO em inglês tem uma respostas a respeito http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23682748/pdo-connection-to-sql-server-times-out

Comment: Você tem o mssql e não o sqlsrv

Comment: mas como seria a query de conexão ? a primeira ?

Comment: O comando ->.fetch não é reconhecido... Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\teste\1.php on line 7

Comment: O comando fetch existe, o erro está dizendo que você está chamando, o método fetch ("a member") de algo que não é objeto("non-object"), ou seja, o seu query deve ter falhado... alias, verifica se você conectou, está utilizando os nomes corretamente

Answer (score 1):

Boa noite.
Caso não tenha as extensões sqlsrv e pdo_sqlsrv, o ideal é tentar com odbc.
Veja como fica:

```
$pdo = new \PDO ("odbc:Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server=localhost;Database=catalogName;app=appName;WISD={$_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST']}",$sqlUser,$sqlPass);
```

Qual versão do PHP está utilizando?
Consegue enviar um print do phpinfo na área da PDO similiar à imagem abaixo?
Veja se na configuração do PHP está habilitado pdo_sqlsrv, pois me parece que este driver você já possui.

[image: PRINT PHPINFO PDO]

Comment: esse server native cliente é isso ou altero para alguma constate ?

Comment: É isso mesmo!!!
Se não tiver o driver odbc é tranquilo encontrar para download.

Comment: veja oq mostrou o pdo do meu phpinfo no comentário da primeira resposta

Comment: Apareceu algum erro usando odbc?
Veja Se o driver 'SQL Server Native Client 11.0' em ferramentas administrativas do windows.

Qualquer coisa, teste isto apenas com 'SQL Server'.
Se funcionar, procure instalar os outros drivers, é mais tranquilo para trabalhar.

    $pdo = new \PDO ("odbc:Driver={SQL Server};Server=localhost;Database=catalogName;app=appName;WISD={$_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST']}",$sqlUser,$sqlPass);

Comment: @Maurivan, é uma alternativa, mas é uma camada a mais para conectar, normalmente, não fica mais lento?E ODBC só windows, certo?

Comment: Ele n exibe erro de conexao, mas n consegui inserir dados ...

Comment: @RodrigoSartoriJarouche, sim, fica mais lento.
Então o ideal é instalar e habilitar pdo_sqlsrv nas extensões do php.
O driver odbc existe para outros SOs também.

Comment: @Maurivan informações extras são sempre úteis! Obrigado!

Comment: MEU CÓDIGO É ESSE http://pastebin.com/FttEiEZb porem qnd rodo ele n exibe erro, mas não insere, pois faço select* no sql studio
Sabé o erro ?

Comment: Cod_AdmRegional é string? Se for integer tem que tirar as aspas...

Comment: É char, mas inseri pelo manager e funcionou ...