# Diferenças quanto ao uso de $this, self, static e parent

Tags: php

Tenho uma dúvida quanto ao uso "adequado" de **$this**, **self**, **static** e **parent** em alguns cenários específicos. Conheço o significado e uso teórico de cada um:

- **$this**: basicamente faz referencia a instância do objeto. Serve para propriedades não estáticas e métodos. Não pode ser utilizado com
  constantes
- **static**: o mesmo que $this, mas é usado para métodos, propriedades estáticas e constantes
- **self**: usado para métodos, propriedades estáticas e constantes. Na prática em uma hierarquia de classes ele faz referência a classe em
  quem que self está sendo escrito
- **parent**: fará referência a classe pai. Poderá ser usado com métodos, propriedades estáticas e constantes

---

No código abaixo a ideia de usar **parent** foi dar a visibilidade de que o método chamado é um método "externo", ou melhor, herdado. Isso estaria correto?

```
<?php

class Pessoa{     

    private $nome;
    private $idade;
    private $sexo;  

    protected function setNome($nome)
    {
        if(is_string($nome)) {
            $this->nome = $nome;
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    protected function setIdade($idade)
    {
        if(is_int($idade)) {
            $this->idade = $idade;
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    protected function setSexo($sexo)
    {
        if($sexo == 'M' || $sexo = "F") {
            $this->sexo = $sexo;
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public function getNome()
    {
        return $this->nome;
    }

    public function getIdade()
    {
        return $this->idade;
    }

    public function getSexo()
    {
        return $this->sexo;
    }
} 

class Funcionario extends Pessoa
{ 
    private $empresa;
    private $salario;

    public function __construct($nome, $idade, $sexo, $empresa, $salario)
    {
        parent::setNome($nome);
        parent::setIdade($idade);
        parent::setSexo($sexo);
        $this->empresa = $empresa;
        $this->salario = $salario;
    }

    public function getEmpresa()
    {
        return $this->empresa;
    }

    public function getSalario()
    {
        return $this->salario;
    }
}

$funcionario = new Funcionario("Yuri", "19", "Masculino", "Tam", "3000");

echo $funcionario->getNome() . ' Trabalha na: ' . $funcionario->getEmpresa() . ' e ganha ' . $funcionario->getSalario();
```

Agora uma pergunta macro: existe alguma receita que sugira quando é melhor utilizar **$this**, **self**, **static** ou **parent**?

Comment: Além do que já está escrito na pergunta? Não.

Comment: Relacionadas: [Qual a diferença entre static::Propriedade, NomeClasse::propriedade, self::propriedade?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/242625/5878), [Qual a diferença entre static e self em PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/6434/5878)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fabio, acredito que esse exemplo que você postou não deve ser seguido (o de usar parent::setNome). Não existe vantagem nenhuma, e se usar parent dessa forma é necessário, provavelmente é um indicativo de uma falha de design.

Se uma classe herda os métodos, então você deve poder usá-los da mesma forma que usaria os métodos da classe herdada.

Agora suponha que você precisa sobrescrever o método setNome na classe filha. Se você o fizer, parent::setNome não vai executar o método sobrescrito, mas sim o método da classe herdada, o que provavelmente não seria o resultado esperado.

Comment: Obrigado Thiago, sua explicação tirou uma dúvida que eu tinha quanto à utilização de parent.

Answer (score 12):

A receita é: **usar aquele que deve ser usado**.

Como você bem descreveu, os quatro fazem coisas distintas, então basta utilizar o **correto**, não existe melhor.

## [parent](http://php.net/manual/pl/keyword.parent.php)

Faz referência a classe pai que foi herdada pela classe atual. Basicamente foi criado para que você não precise, dentro da classe filha, ficar explicitando qual é a classe pai de onde será chamado o método, acessar o atributo, constante, etc.

```
<?php

class A {
    function example() {
        echo "I am A::example() and provide basic functionality.<br />\n";
    }
}

class B extends A {
    function example() {
        echo "I am B::example() and provide additional functionality.<br />\n";
        parent::example();
    }
}

$b = new B;

// This will call B::example(), which will in turn call A::example().
$b->example();

// Saída:
// I am B::example() and provide additional functionality.
// I am A::example() and provide basic functionality.
```

<sup>Exemplo retirado da [documentação oficial](http://php.net/manual/pl/keyword.parent.php). Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/69LN0X) | [Repl.it](https://repl.it/MxNt/0)</sup>

No código acima, o método `example` é reescrito em `B`, porém, sua referência em `A` permanece através de `parent`. A única diferença de se fazer, aqui, `A::example()`, é de não precisar explicitar o nome da classe que foi herdada. Se o nome da classe `A` mudasse para `W`, bastaria apenas alterar na declaração de `B`, `class B extends W`, e não no código inteiro. O resultado é exatamente o mesmo.

## this

Referência à própria **instância**. Tudo que pertence a instância estará disponível em `$this`. Métodos estáticos e constantes pertencem à própria classe e, portanto, não são acessível neste objeto (em PHP). Adaptando um pouco o exemplo anterior, podemos fazer:

```
<?php

class A {
    function example() {
        echo "I am A::example() and provide basic functionality.<br />\n";
    }
}

class B extends A {
    function example() {
        echo "I am B::example() and provide additional functionality.<br />\n";
    }

    function main() {
        $this->example();
        parent::example();
    }
}

$b = new B;

// This will call B::example(), which will in turn call A::example().
$b->main();

// Saída:
// I am B::example() and provide additional functionality.
// I am A::example() and provide basic functionality.
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/FIyMnO) | [Repl.it](https://repl.it/MxPS/0)</sup>

## self

A referência em `self` aponta sempre para a **própria classe** onde é utilizado e é essa a diferença para o `static`. Ao utilizar `self` em `A`, a referência será para a classe A e quando utilizado em `B` a referência será a B. Isso influencia muito, por exemplo, quando você quer definir o retorno em um método:

```
<?php

class A {
    public function example() {
        return new self;
    }
}

class B extends A {

}

$b = new B();
$obj = $b->example();

echo get_class($obj), PHP_EOL;

// Saída:
// A
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/j60sSX) | [Repl.it](https://repl.it/MxS4/0)</sup>

Perceba que ao definir o retorno como `self`, será retornado um objeto instância de A, não de B.

## static

Semelhante ao `self` o `static` sempre fará referência à classe da **instância utilizada**. As vezes, o comportamento do `static` é resumido como um *`self` preguiçoso*, pois ele não define a referência na hora. Executando o mesmo exemplo acima, alterando `self` para `static`, temos:

```
<?php

class A {
    public function example() {
        return new static;
    }
}

class B extends A {

}

$b = new B();
$obj = $b->example();

echo get_class($obj), PHP_EOL;

// Saída:
// B
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/Fw2bwM) | [Repl.it](https://repl.it/MxTB/0)</sup>

Mesmo que `static` seja utilizado na classe A, o retorno será uma nova instância de B, pois o `new static` foi invocado a partir de uma instância de B e, como dito, `static` sempre faz referência à classe da instância atual.

**Resumindo...**

- `parent` deve ser utilizado quando precisa referenciar a classe pai;
- `this` deve ser utilizado para referenciar a instância corrente;
- `self` deve ser utilizado para referenciar a classe onde é aplicado;
- `static` deve ser utilizado para referenciar a classe da instância onde é aplicado.

Comment: Acredito que a maior dúvida seja, todos os métodos foram herdados, devo fazer referência aos métodos herdados utilizando $this, ou seja, trabalhar com os métodos que foram herdados, ou devo acessa-los na classe pai via parent?

Comment: Se o método foi herdado, `this`, pois pertence à instância. O `parent` será utilizado apenas para invocar um método da classe pai em caso de conflito ou métodos estáticos.