# Undefined variable em PHP

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos

Estou tentando executar este código PHP usando orientação a objetos e estou tendo dificuldades.

```
<?php 
class Circulo { 

    // declaração de propriedades 
    public $raio = 0;
    public $area = 0; 

    // declaração de método
    public function mostraArea(){ 
        echo $this->area;
    } 

    // declaração de método 
    public function calculaArea(){ 
        $this->area = 3.14*$raio*$raio;
    } 
} 

$circ1 = new Circulo;
$circ1->raio = 10;
$circ1->calculaArea();
$circ1->mostraArea();
?>
```

E no navegador o resultado é:

> Notice: Undefined variable: raio in D:\Web\LocalUser\PPI_11611208 slide45a.php on line 12
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: raio in D:\Web\LocalUser\PPI_11611208\slide45a.php on line 12 0

- Como a variável raio não está definida? Sendo que atribuí um valor a ela na linha 20.

Provavelmente deve ser uma questão básica de conceito POO que eu não entendi?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A variável `$raio` não existe mesmo. O que é definido na sua classe é uma propriedade que tem um escopo diferente de uma variável local. Sua chamada sempre se refere ou ao objeto (`$this`) ou a classe/super classe (`self`/`parent`)

Mude:

```
public function calculaArea() { 
    $this->area = 3.14 * $raio * $raio;
}
```

Para:

```
public function calculaArea() { 
    $this->area = 3.14 * $this->raio * $this->raio;
}
```

Assim o calculo será feito em cima propriedade e não de uma variável (que não existe).

**Relacionadas:**

[Diferenças quanto ao uso de $this, self, static e parent](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/247723/91)

[Quando usar self vs $this em PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/575/91)

Answer (score 0):

O ***erro*** é devido a variável `$raio` não se encontrar dentro do método `calculaArea`, para utilizar uma variável de fora do método, utilize o `$this->nome_da_variavel`