# Usar/alterar propriedade de uma classe estendida e imprimir pela instância

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, classes, herança

### Cenário exemplo

#### Pasta raiz

- ClasseA.php
- ClasseB.php
- index.php

Arquivo: `classeA.php`

```
class ClasseA 
{
    public $retorno = null;
    public $error   = "Erro desconhecido";

    function __construct
    {
       $this -> func_A();
    }

    public function func_A()
    {
        require_once 'classeB.php';
        $obj = new ClasseB;
        $obj -> func_B();
    }

}
```

Arquivo: `classeB.php`

```
class ClasseB extends ClasseA
{
    public function func_B()
    {
       $this -> error = "Erro em func_B";
    }

}
```

Arquivo: `index.php`

```
require_once 'ClasseA.php';

$obj = new ClasseA;
echo ($obj -> retorno != null) ? $obj -> retorno : $obj -> error;
```

---

### Problema

Meu retorno de `index.php` é: "Erro desconhecido".

O que esperava: "Erro em func_B".

---

### Dúvida

- Por que a propriedade `error` da `ClasseA` não é alterada?
- Quais possíveis soluções?

Comment: Acho que aqui tem a sua resposta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/247723/diferen%C3%A7as-quanto-ao-uso-de-this-self-static-e-parent

Comment: veja a resposta do  Anderson Carlos Woss

Comment: Seu problema é que ao instanciar um objeto `ClasseB ` atribuir o valor de error dele, você está alterando apenas desta instancia e não da instancia da classe `ClasseA `. Talvez chamando `parent::error  = "Erro em func_B"` em `func_B` funcione, mas acho difícil já que cada instancia independe da outra

Comment: @AlvaroAlves, não consegui extrair minha resposta deste link, poderia dizer o trecho por favor?

Comment: @edsonalves Chamar por `parent::` teria que ser estático, e se for estático não iria alterá-lo.

Comment: Não é a resposta em si, mas como você está tratando este problema, como a resposta do Maniero diz: "Este cenário é atípico, e duvido que ele tenha serventia real, mas se está querendo fazer algo real, parece ser engenharia errada e o caminho deve ser bem diferente deste tentado."

Comment: @AlvaroAlves Pode ser que sim, pode ser que não, pode ser talvez, etc... kkk

Comment: @rbz te entendo, às vezes tenho algumas idéias mirabolantes por aqui também, somos criadores de coisas, é normal às vezes criarmos algo que não é compreendido pelos outros kkk

Comment: @AlvaroAlves Complicado! rs... É muito particular a forma de "escrever um código", e as vezes poderia sim utilizar de outra forma, mas se dessa forma me ajuda a organizar, entender, funcionar, etc, ou teria de ser um argumento/exemplo muito bom para tirar a ideia (o que é difícil porque não há todo contexto), ou chegar um ponto que não tem opção, e sim, precisa mudar! rs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eu admito que posso estar enganado, porque PHP costuma ter comportamentos esquisitos, vou responder pela lógica universal que conheço, até porque não consigo reproduzir isto porque só tenho PHP nesses IDEs *online* que entram em *loop* com uma construção dessas do jeito que precisa por neles.

Você está criando um objeto totalmente diferente dentro de `func_A()`, mesmo que ele seja derivado de `ClasseA`, este objeto guardado em `$obj` dentro de `func_A()` não é o mesmo objeto que está operando em `ClasseA`. Quando você usa o `$this` no objeto de `ClasseB`, ou seja, do `$obj`, não está mudando o `$this` de de `$obj` global, são objetos muito diferentes, e o que você está mandando imprimir é esse objeto apenas.

Lembrando que o `$obj` interno da classe só existe enquanto um objeto dessa classe existir, mas ele é completamente separado, apenas possuí um vínculo de [associação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/86715/101), é uma composição (a groso modo um objeto dentro do outro), não é herança (um objeto único com dois modelos).

O fato de duas variáveis completamente diferentes terem o nome pode ter dificultado o entendimento.

Este cenário é atípico, e duvido que ele tenha serventia real, mas se está querendo fazer algo real, parece ser engenharia errada e o caminho deve ser bem diferente deste tentado.

Comment: Mas se estou declarando `$this -> error = "Erro em func_B";` e não "tem acesso" a propriedade `error` da `ClasseA`, e/ou também não exista essa propriedade em `ClasseB`, deveria acusar um erro (falha do PHP!?). Então não existiria forma de alterar essa propriedade nessa estrutura?

Comment: Eu não disse que não tem acesso `ClasseA`, eu disse que não tem acesso ao outro objeto completamente diferente, o problema não é ter duas classes é ter dois objetos. O `$error` existe em `ClasseB` porque esta classes deriva de `CLasseA` que tem o campo (não é uma propriedade) que você quer, mas é de um outro objeto, outra instância. Os dois tem acendedor de cigarro, mas um é o seu carro e outro é do meu carro. Se você ligar o seu não vai esquentar o meu. tem como alterar, mas depende do caso, esse cenário serve para nada, em cenário real eu pensaria como fazer.

Comment: Mas o objeto de A está no index. A função de A cria um de B para alterar sua propriedade. Então isso não existe? Não funciona? Se não houvesse o objeto de B então teria como alterar ? Eu não entendi se há uma forma...

Comment: Bom, aí já está usando termos inadequados e não sei do que está falando. Tudo funcionaria se estive feito do jeito certo, e nada funcionará se fizer do jeito errado, não importa se tem um objeto de `ClasseB` ou não. Eu não posso dizer o que é certo porque sequer sei para que isto serve, até onde posso observar, serva para nada, mas é só porque é confuso e não indica o objetivo.

Comment: Mas se for pensar assim, então tudo entraria na questão do "problema XY", e nada iria responder a questão. O problema está no cenário exemplo, é alterar a propriedade da classe estendida. Eu que fico sem entender os upvotes! rs

Comment: Não posso dizer tudo, mas esse parece ser um problema XY, você pediu a explicação do mecanismo, eu respondi. Agora quer a solução para um problema, é outra questão completamente diferente. Porém para perguntar sobre a solução precisa ser muito claro quanto ao problema. Neste momento não parece saber qual é o problema. Quando não se sabe onde quer chegar qualquer caminho serve porque todos te levarão para o lugar errado. Cenários artificiais só funciona para o mecanismo, em problema real depende do contexto e completo, não pode faltar qualquer detalhes,tem q saber qual é o problema precisamente

Comment: A lógica é a ClasseA, ser uma classe "mestre", ela recebe uma chamada e processa conforme o diretório / arquivo / classe /método dinamicamente.
Então sempre irá chamar uma classe/método sendo esse método, o último processamento, e caso tiver erro, ele irá setar a propriedade "error" da ClasseA, se não tiver erros, irá setar a propriedade "retorno" da ClasseA, por exemplo. Pelo visto, terei que retornar um array ou json, e processar ela na ClasseA, correto!?

Comment: Não sei, pra mim tudo isso está errado e a solução é outra, mas novamente, só vendo todos detalhes, de verdade, tentar programar em cima de de coisas artificiais não dá certo, não tem semântica, então tudo pode ser certou o u errado.

Comment: Vou criar uma pergunta mais específica, aí se ela não der, é praticamente "jogue tudo fora", aí a minha pergunta será "me mostre como fazer" porque encerrariam as opções, isso se antes não for fechada por "ampla demais" ou "baseada em opiniões"! rs

Answer (score 1):

Não é exatamente o que você estava tentando, mas talvez isso possa te ajudar:

```
class ClasseA
{
    public $retorno = null;
    protected $error = "Erro desconhecido";

    public function __get($name)
    {
        require_once 'ClasseB.php';
        $obj = new ClasseB;
        $obj->func_B();

        return $obj->$name;
    }
}
```

Ademais, não sei bem qual seria a utilidade de chamar a classeA ou invés de instanciar direto a classeB (já que estende a A). O erro no seu código (como melhor explicado pelo Maniero), é que a a variavel $obj só existe dentro do contexto da função chamada e não sobrescreve os atributos da class.

Agora, usando a magic function **__get**, você consegue sobrescrever a chamada dos métodos não públicos.

Comment: Isso não iria me resolver, pois não seria só 1 propriedade, seriam várias! Mas agradeço a resposta. :)

Comment: Sim, no caso o método __get intercepta qualquer propriedade não pública (protected), e ai você pode inserir sua lógica de validação para determinado fim.

Comment: Outra solução é criar uma factory, ai ao invés de instanciar diretamente o objeto, você chama a factory que te devolve a instância correta do objeto desejado.